# Leaflet.js map not loading properly

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

I have a popup container with a leaflet map in it. A button on the main page activates the function to get the users location and draw the map on the popup. However when the popup shows up the map is only partly loaded and isn't focusing on where I am. When I open the console it auto adjusts and is perfect. I've seen posts with similar problems but they link to github pages that no longer exist.

this is my geolocation file

```
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        var map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 12);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=sJdX2R69yUO7n4qEW4gl', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>' ,
        }).addTo(map);
        console.log(latitude, longitude);
}, error => {
    console.log(error.code);
},{
    enableHighAccuracy: true
});
}
```

and this where the map is being drawn

```
<div class="form-popup" id="hackContainer">
                <div id="warning"></div>
                <script src="js/geolocation.js"></script>
                <div id="map"></div>
```

and this is the button that triggers the function

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="getLocation()">Give Location</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `map.invalidateSize();`, to rerender the map size.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        var map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 12);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=sJdX2R69yUO7n4qEW4gl', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>' ,
        }).addTo(map);
        console.log(latitude, longitude);
        map.invalidateSize();
}
```

Comment: Should not you rather wait for the popup to be open?

Comment: Yes sure but I thought the popup is already open when he loads the map. `A button on the main page activates the function to get the users location and draw the map on the popup`

Comment: I probably didn't explain it well enough aha. I have a popup that holds the map and several other elements when you press the getLocation button it draws the map and gets the location. I have a separate button that opens the pop up. I managed to find a fix anyway. in the function that changes the popups display from none to table I added this `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));` and that worked